# How do I prove this statement by contradiction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The sum of an irrational number and a rational number is irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove this statement using proof by contradiction. Let $\mathit{a}$ denote an irrational number and let $\mathit{b}$ denote a rational number. Also, let's assume that their sum is a rational number, $\mathit{c}$. $$\therefore a + b = c$$ $$\Rightarrow a = c -b$$ As both c and b are rational, they can be written as a quotient of two integers (as the definition of a rational number is a number that can be expressed as a quotient of two integers). Therefore, let $\mathit a = \frac{x}{y}$ and let $\mathit b = \frac{n}{m}$. Then we can rewrite $\mathit a = c - b$ as: $$ a = \frac{x}{y} + \frac{n}{m}$$ Obtaining a common denominator, we get: $$a = \frac{xm}{ym} + \frac{yn}{ym}$$ $$= \frac{xm - yn}{ym}$$
As $\mathit {\{m, n, x, y\}}\in \Bbb Z $ (i.e. they are integers) we can say that both the numerator and the denominator of the fraction are integers. Therefore, we have created a contradiction as we said at the start that $\mathit{a}$ was an irrational number but now we can clearly see that it is rational (as the definition of a rational number is a number which can be expressed as a quotient of integers).   Q.E.D.

In conclusion, the sum of a rational and an irrational number is an irrational number

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x$ is irrational, $y$ is rational, and $x+y=z$ is rational.  Subtract $y$ from both sides, yielding $x=z-y,$ with $y$ and $z$ rational.  But a difference of two rational numbers is rational, contradicting the assumption that $x$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Let uppercase letters denote irrationals.

Then

$$A+b=c$$ is not possible because

$$A=b-c=d$$ is incompatible.